# Why are SBT projects declared as lazy vals?

Tags: sbt

Per the [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html), "A project is defined by declaring a lazy val of type Project."

That is certainly the norm, and is what we are doing, but I was wondering what if any is the reason it needs to be lazy.

Using a regular `val` instead of `lazy val` *seems* to work. Of course using strict vals results in the project definitions being initialized in order, which means forward references don't work, requiring projects to be defined in dependency order.

For a relatively large build, with 53 interdependent projects, having ordering enforced is actually a Good Thing™, so I was wondering if there's an actual reason for using lazy val -- besides allowing definitions to occur in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 12):

This is a common "best practice". I haven't seen anybody explicitly state this, but from my experience this practice is related to a few features of sbt.

1. sbt parses **any** `*.sbt` file
2. sbt evaluates an `*.sbt` file top to bottom
3. you can created dependencies between everything in multiple sbt files

Now imagine you want to structure your `build.sbt` for readability. We have some common settings and 3 projects (a root and two builds)

```
val root = project.in(file("."))
      .settings(commonSettings)
      .aggregate(api, server)

val api = project.in(file("api"))
      .settings(commonSettings)
      .settings(name := "server")

val server= project.in(file("api"))
      .settings(commonSettings)
      .settings(name := "api")
      .dependsOn(api)

val commonSettings = Seq(organization := "com.example")
```

sbt won't start as multiple things are wrong in this `build.sbt`

1. The `api` and `server` module are referenced in the `root` project before they are defined
2. `commonSettings` is referenced before its definition in all projects

Without making everything `lazy` it gets hard to refactor your build files. This is the reasons all sbt documentation uses `lazy val`s every. To avoid confusion and frustration for first time users.

hope that helps,
Muki

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong here. So the main idea of `lazy val` usage is to allow reordering declarations right?

Comment: That's correct @MinhThai :)